# Copying over all the elements to a new page

Tags: 8

I have a website where we post our events. We would love to copy the 2018 event post and then edit it, rather than copying over all the elements to a new page. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) There are a myriad ways to have events displayed on a Drupal site. From that little information it's impossible to give you an other answer than "Yes, it's possible". Duplicate all 2018 events and edit them. Or get all 2018 events and change their date. Unfortunately it's ambiguous what "new page" means to you. Maybe you can edit your question for clarification. Many thanks

Comment: drupal.org's search interface does leave a lot to be desired, but the two key words to search for are "copy" or more specifically "clone". And to narrow down the types of results by using the search facets on the right hand side of the page. It might also help to join one of the Drupal chats - Drupal Slack or drupalchat.me (EU-friendly).

Answer (score 1):

If your events are part of a content type, then try this module. It should let you clone a node

https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_node_clone